# debian 8 shutdown dialog change hibernate button method

Tags: debian, hibernate, dialog

Hello I have problem with hibernate on my HP635 notebook.
Having Debian jessie install with minimal MATE desktop enviroment

I give the hibernation to life (despite of special setup with mounted swapfile instead of swap partition) but it only works when I type hibernate or s2disk in root console.

Choosing system > shutdown and then in dialog choosing hibernate causes system switching to text mode but after while system "is back"

Also tried do some config in `/etc/pm`, but then I googled that pm-utils no longer works in jessie or something like that

My question is where are some suspend/hibernate scripts in jessie, I remember that in squeeze I had same problem and resolve it by something like `SLEEP_MODULE="uswsusp"` in `/etc/pm`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is just something MATE related. For example, I use Enlightenment/E17 as a desktop environment and in the file `{install directory}/etc/enlightenment/sysactions.conf` you can choose the actual command called from hibernate/power off/suspend/...